# Display Correct Row based on Candy Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Goal:
If a person has two candy number, number 1 should always display first. No need to display candy number 2.
If a person does not have number 1, it should display number 2 instead.

```
Display all data
(int)(int)  (nvarchar) (int)
Id  fId     Name     Candy Number
---------------------------------
1    12     Kimn                1
2    12     Kimn                2
3    19     Lisa                1
4    15     John                2
5    16     Maria               2
6    16     Maria               1
7    17     Mao                 2



Requested result:
Id  fId     Name     Candy Number
---------------------------------
1    12     Kimn                1
3    19     Lisa                1
4    15     John                2
6    16     Maria               1
7    17     Mao                 2
```

Problem:
It doesn't work so well for me to display it.
Tried using case and end in where statement but the code didn't fit to the purpose.

Any idea?

```
select *
from
    table
where
    candynumber = 
        CASE WHEN b.MatchType = 1 
                THEN 1
            ELSE 2
        END
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be using `row_number()` window function:

```
select Id, fId, Name, Candy_Number from (
    select your_table.*, row_number() over(partition by fId order by Candy_Number) as rn from your_table
) t 
where rn = 1
order by id
```

This gives one row per `fId`, with  lower Candy_Number.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
SELECT          candyWrapper.ID,
                candyWrapper.FID,
                outerHardCandy.Name,
                outerHardCandy.Number
FROM            (SELECT     innerSoftCandy.Name,
                            CASE
                                WHEN (SUM(innerSoftCandy.Number) = 3) OR (SUM(innerSoftCandy.Number) = 1) THEN 1
                                WHEN (SUM(innerSoftCandy.Number) = 2) THEN 2
                            END AS Number
                FROM        Candy innerSoftCandy
                GROUP BY    innerSoftCandy.Name
                ) outerHardCandy
INNER JOIN      Candy candyWrapper ON (outerHardCandy.Name = candyWrapper.Name AND outerHardCandy.Number = candyWrapper.Number)
ORDER BY        candyWrapper.ID
```

You can see this here -> http://rextester.com/BBD89608